# How to make HTML element always appear when below a certain window size, but only sometimes when window is larger?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make my "sticky" navigation bar appear under the following circumstances:

1. If the user's window is 615px or smaller
2. If the user has scrolled a bit down the page, regardless of window size

My attempt at fulfilling both circumstances is not working. Here is the code I am using now to try to make both work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // run test on initial page load
    checkSize();

    // run test on resize of the window
    $(window).resize(checkSize);


    function checkSize() {
        // .sticky appears when CSS media query fires (this one fires at max-width: 615px)
        if ($(".col").css("width") == "100%") {
                $('.sticky').css("visibility", "visible");
                $('.sticky').css("opacity", "1");
                $('.sticky').css("display", "block");
        }
        // otherwise, make .sticky only appear when user scrolls down a bit
        else {
            $('.js-section-about').waypoint(function (direction) {
                if (direction == 'down') {
                    $('.sticky').css("visibility", "visible");
                    $('.sticky').css("opacity", "1");
                } else {
                    $('.sticky').css("opacity", "0");
                    $('.sticky').css("visibility", "hidden");
                }
            }, {
                offset: '35%'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The expected outcome is that the sticky nav acts as expected under each circumstance. What is actually happening is that my code is acting exactly like before: sticky nav is invisible by default, and appears once you scroll down the page.

I previously was only working with the nested if / else statement (the waypoints one), and it was working great. Now it acts like my parent if / else statement isn't even there.

I am very new to jQuery and web design in general, but this solution seems to me like it should work. Any ideas why it doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overthinking this. Why not handle the small size case with a plain media query?

```
<script>
$('.js-section-about').waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $('.sticky').css("display", "block");
    } else {
        $('.sticky').css("display", "none");
    }
});
</script>
<style>
@media screen and (max-width: 615px) {
  #bun { visibility: visible; opacity: 1; display: block; }
}
</style>
<div class="sticky" id="bun"> Navigation Bar </div>
```

id automatically has CSS priority over class, but there are also other ways to do it.